# Merging a string to a structured string

Tags: java, string, substring, concatenation

If I have a string like this:

```
FOO BAR YY
- foo bar y
- foo bar x
FOO BAR AA
- foo bar z
- foo bar y
```

And another String like this:

```
"FOO BAR YY;- foo bar new entry"
```

I need a generic way to find the string `FOO BAR YY` or a similar string of the first level and concatenate my substring `-foo bar k` inside a new line to get this result:

```
FOO BAR YY
- foo bar new entry
- foo bar y
- foo bar x
FOO BAR AA
- foo bar z
- foo bar y
```

Is there an elegant way to find and insert instead the substring?

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted, perfectly reasonable question IMHO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An elegant way would be to implement a parser (which parses the original string into convenient data structure) and a generator (which creates the string back). This is the rough sketch how to do it (using Java-7):

```
public class MyStructure {
    private Map<String, List<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    public MyStructure(String src) {
        parse(src);
    }

    private void parse(String src) {
        String curKey = null;
        List<String> curList = null; 
        for(String line : src.trim().split("\n")) {
            if(line.startsWith("- ")) {
                if(curList == null) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected line");
                }
                curList.add(line);
            } else {
                if(curKey != null) {
                    map.put(curKey, curList);
                }
                curKey = line;
                curList = new ArrayList<>();
            }
        }
        if(curKey != null)
            map.put(curKey, curList);
    }

    public void add(String key, String value) {
        List<String> list = map.get(key);
        if(list == null) {
            list = new ArrayList<>();
            map.put(key, list);
        }
        list.add(0, value);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            sb.append(entry.getKey()).append("\n");
            for(String item : entry.getValue())
                sb.append(item).append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Here's usage example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyStructure ms = new MyStructure("FOO BAR YY\n" + 
            "- foo bar y\n" + 
            "- foo bar x\n" + 
            "FOO BAR AA\n" + 
            "- foo bar z\n" + 
            "- foo bar y");
    System.out.println("Before: " + ms);
    String toAdd = "FOO BAR YY;- foo bar new entry";
    String[] fields = toAdd.split(";", 2);
    ms.add(fields[0], fields[1]);
    System.out.println("After: " + ms);
}
```

Output:

```
Before: FOO BAR YY
- foo bar y
- foo bar x
FOO BAR AA
- foo bar z
- foo bar y

After: FOO BAR YY
- foo bar new entry
- foo bar y
- foo bar x
FOO BAR AA
- foo bar z
- foo bar y
```

Having data structure is much better as it will allow later to do other operations conveniently. For example, you can easily support items removal or reordering.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use a suitable data structure to store your structured data.  Rather than a `String` you could store your data as a `Multimap` (for example [Guava Multimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)).

So your existing data would be represented like

```
Multimap<String, String> myData = ArrayListMultimap.create();
myData.put("FOO BAR YY", "- foo bar y");
myData.put("FOO BAR YY", "- foo bar x");
myData.put("FOO BAR AA", "- foo bar z");
myData.put("FOO BAR AA", "- foo bar y");
```

then adding new data becomes trivial

```
myData.put("FOO BAR YY", "- foo bar new entry");
```

or in your case:

```
String[] entryLine = "FOO BAR YY;- foo bar new entry".split(";", 2);
myData.put(entryLine[0], entryLine[1]);
```

to pull out all the data for a specific key:

```
myData.get("FOO BAR YY")
```

returns

```
["- foo bar y", "- foo bar x", "- foo bar new entry"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but my answer would be something like this:

```java
String list = "FOO BAR YY\n"
    + "- foo bar y\n"
    + "- foo bar x\n"
    + "FOO BAR AA\n"
    + "- foo bar z\n"
    + "- foo bar y\n";
String entry = "FOO BAR YY;- foo bar new entry";

//The first position will be the term to search and the second the new entry
//The second parameter puts a limit so it only splits the string in two,
//this way it only takes out the first appearence
String[] entrySplit = entry.split(";", 2);
//We split by the search term so we can insert the new line
//We make sure the search term is the only thing in its line
String[] listSplit = list.split("^" + entrySplit[0] + "$", 2);
//We must insert the search term again
list = listSplit[0] + entrySplit[0] + "\n" + entrySplit[1] + listSplit[1];
```

This solution is arguably elegant. A more elegant solution would be having your list in a `Map<String,String[]>` or a similar data structure, but if you must work with Strings this is what I would do.

---

EDIT: I see other answers like @Tagir Valeev 's cover the `Map` solution. It is, indeed, better and more efficient (and more elegant) to store the list in a data structure.